# Using global modelattribute in another controller advice in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two global controller advice classes defined as followings.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalModelAttributes {

  @ModelAttribut("mkey")
  public String mKey() {
    return "aValue";
  }
}
```

Another class for exception handling.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static final String ERROR_4_XX = "error/4xx";

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({InvalidRequestException.class}
    )
    public ModelAndView handleBadRequest() {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(ERROR_4_XX);
        result.addObject(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, "An invalid value provided");
        return result;
    }

}
```

And in the `error/4xx.html` I have used the value of `mkey` assuming that I would get the value in the view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" href="/css/error.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="bg-container">
          <h1 class="text-err">
            <span th:text="${mkey}"></span>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the value is not printed and I found following link(8 years old but still valid) where it is mentioned that that kind of value is not available to exception view.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

- Model enhancement methods (for adding additional data to the model)
  annotated with @ModelAttribute. Note that these attributes are not
  available to the exception handling views.

I believe there would be a way to get those global model attribute.
I don't want to replicate those model attributes in `@ExceptionHandler` as there are many of those and many of `@ExceptionHandler` too.